# MySQL update multiple table for kunde and profil

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "profil" and "kunde". "profil" got the email and password. "kunde" got the bio, username and email as index from "profil". "kunde" got the primary key username.
I want to update the username bio and passwort at once

`UPDATE profil, kunde SET kunde.username = ?, kunde.bio = ?, profil.passwort = ? WHERE profil.email = ?;`

the error code i got

`#1062 - duplicated entry 'Kneipengänger60' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: So show the current data, and the data you tried to update. That sounds like you just duplicated a primary key, not that there's a problem with updating multiple target tables.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update two tables in a single statement. However you can use transactions to ensure that the two statements are updated as a single unit. If one fails both are rolled back.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE profil
SET profil.passwort = ?
FROM profil, kunde
WHERE profil.id = kunde.id //Here you use the secondary key and primary keys to link the tables
and profil.email = ?;

UPDATE kunde
SET kunde.username = ?, kunde.bio = ?
FROM profil, kunde
WHERE profil.id = kunde.id //Here you use the secondary key and primary keys to link the tables
and profil.email = ?;

COMMIT;
```